# NodeJS SHA1 get raw output (PHP SHA1 raw output equivalent)

Tags: node.js, sha1

In PHP, the code below returns the raw output of the SHA1 of the "string"

```
sha1("string", true);
```

What is the nodeJS equivalent of getting the SHA1 raw output?

Edit: I made some test and this line:

```
crypto.createHash('sha1').update('string').digest('base64');
```

generates same output as php's

```
base64_encode(sha1('string', true));
```

My issue occurs when I try to concatenate a string and the result of sha1, the get the sha1 again:

```
base64_encode(sha1(sha1("string", true) . "another string", true))
```

Different with nodejs:

```
var stringhash = crypto.createHash('sha1').update('string').digest();
crypto.createHash('sha1').update("another string" + stringhash).digest('base64')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
let digest   = crypto.createHash('sha1').update('string').digest();
process.stdout.write( digest );
```

**EDIT**: the equivalent of your second example:

```
let hash1  = crypto.createHash('sha1').update('string').digest();
let hash2  = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(hash1).update('another string');
let digest = hash2.digest('base64');
```

Comment: Based on nodejs documentation, in .digest():
"If encoding is provided a string will be returned; otherwise a Buffer is returned."

"Buffer" is the equivalent of the raw output of PHP's sha1?

Comment: @whoknows a `Buffer` in Node.js contains binary ("raw") data in the form of a `UInt8Array`, which is likely equivalent to what the PHP code returns.